# Load jQuery Only If Not Present without document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any way to load jQuery file if it's not present without using `document.write`

```
<script>
   window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
</script>
```

this way is good but it has major issue because if the visitor  has slow connection the browser will prevent it from executing

when it happen I get this warning

> file is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY
>   be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor
>   network connectivity

I tried many solutions but nothing worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a load callback to the IFFE that will be executed when the script loads or invoked immediately if jQuery exists.

```js
var load = function(){
  // your jQuery code goes here
  $('#hello').html('jQuery Loaded');
};

(function(window, loadCallback){
  if(!window.jQuery){
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
    script.onload = loadCallback;
    
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }else{
    loadCallback();
  }
})(window, load);
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: I was about to write the same answer, is there a bennefit to appending this script in head instad of body ? and is the script.type really needed ?

Comment: I think this depends on if any scripts require jquery to be loaded first. If that is the case then the head will be a good place to inject the script.

Comment: You can drop the type assignment but where you append the script should be based on what your page is doing and if other scripts have a dependency on the appended script.

Comment: It won't work  I always get $ or jQuery not defined https://jsfiddle.net/jcta3rvz/1/

Comment: let me know if you any have issues with the latest update

Comment: It's work flawlessly  I tried many solutions and none worked.  Thank you very much for your time and effort I appreciate that.